# Site Redirecting to wp-signup.php

Tags: multisite, htaccess, migration, wp-config

I migrated content from our production server to our dev server in an attempt to sync all environments. I used the All-In-One WP Migration plugin.

Now, when I access dev.domain.com I am forwarded to http://dev.domain.com/wp-signup.php?new=dev.domain.com

It sounds like one of the database values must be incorrect and WordPress is forwarding me here because of it. If I disable Multisite, everything seems to function properly.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(wp-config\.php|readme\.html|license\.txt)">
 Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
 </FilesMatch>
```

and my wp-config:

```
/** Multisite / Wordpress Network **/
 define('MULTISITE', true);
 define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
 define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'dev.domain.com');
 define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
 define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
 /** fix for Multisite 'SubDomains' - Not Working for me :( */
 define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
 define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
 define('COOKIEPATH', '');
 define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Comment: By request I'm linking my related answer here from another thread that deals with potential database conflicts after changing your Multisite to a new domain and/or converting a single site to Multisite: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/356251/152624

Answer (score 31):

For me it was changing old domain entries in database tables `wp_blogs` and `wp_site` to the new domain of the multisite's main domain.

I haven't done this after the migration to a new domain.

Comment: This answer should be higher up and everywhere. Where have you been my past two weeks of problem solving? Nothing else working..? André Kelling has the answer!

Comment: Awesome, found this answer after 2 hours of frustration... Made me realize always do an SQL query to replace strings...

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: SONOVA....!!!!! .... Thanks.  1000 upboats for you

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to add these to your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', '' );    
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://dev.domain.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://dev.domain.com' );
```

So in its entirety, you'll have:

```
    $base = '/';
    /** Multisite / Wordpress Network **/
    define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://dev.domain.com' );
    define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://dev.domain.com' );
    define( 'MULTISITE', true );
    define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
    define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'dev.domain.com' );
    define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
    define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
    /** fix for Multisite 'SubDomains' - Not Working for me :( */
    define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/' );
    define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );
    define( 'COOKIEPATH', '' );
    define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH', '' );
    define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://dev.domain.com' );
```

And be sure to check your dbprefix_options table in the database for all domain references.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I added the settings you indicated above. Now I see: "Object Moved This document may be found here" .. The link goes to the same page I am on (dev.domain.com/wp-admin)

Comment: With the NOBLOGREDIRECT definition as 'dev.domain.com', I get a redirect failure from firefox.

Comment: Did you have an 'http://' before it?

Comment: Removing the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE, PATH_CURRENT_SITE, and SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE definitions yield 'Error establishing a database connection' .. which is interesting.

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry. -- define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://dev.domain.com');

Comment: I think that's because of the SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE. Let me think here...  Have you added $base = '/' variable?

Answer (score 1):

For me, in addition to the changes above, it turned out to be a DNS configuration issue with my hosting provider. When WP was initially installed as a single site there was a `*.mydomain.com` entry in the DNS pointing to `mydomain.com`. The the site moved to multisite and all worked as expected. Finally when we moved back to single site I started getting the error above. Removing the `*.mydomain.com` entry from my DNS did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share my solution that worked 
go to your database table wp_options and make sure the WWW is added so the url is https://www.domain.com and not https://domain.com do this for both siteurl and home table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding to Baxter Jones's solution with a little more context with the original question. I manually changed the records in the options table for the fields 'siteurl' and 'home' from 127.0.0.1/wordpress to be http://dev.domain.com/. This worked for me after I made the other suggested changes for the wp-config file.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. After migration I have changed from "new.domain.com" to "www.domain.com" (at database through phpmyadmin), but seems like the new sitedomain need to be without www, just "domain.com"

Comment: Are you sure? Is DNS set up correctly for www, and is your web server set up to treat www as part of the WordPress site's virtual host? Are you sure you aren't actually using www? Some modern browsers hide it in the address bar even if you are using www.