# Why is WordPress Multisite redirecting to wp-signup.php and how to fix it?

Tags: multisite, redirect, wp-config, wp-signup

I have recently set up a second blog on my Wordpress multisite. The primary blog on the Multisite is `www.example.com`, and the second blog I have set up two days ago is `www.example2.org`.

Unfortunately, when going to `www.example2.org`, WordPress redirects to `https://www.example.com/wp-signup.php?new=`

On the same server, I have set up a corresponding test Multisite, with `test.example.com` being the primary blog and `test.example2.org` the second blog. It is working without a problem.

The Multisite-related `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php` settings are the same for both the test and the live Multisite, so that wouldn't be the problem. I've also verified that on the live Multisite I have `www.example2.org` correctly set in the `wp_blogs` table, and also it is correctly set as `https://www.example2.org` on the `siteurl` and `home` rows of the `wp_2_options` table (the `_2_` part corresponding to the blog ID on the Multisite).

I would appreciate any suggestions on why this redirect is happening and/or how to resolve it. I don't even know which file is issuing the redirect (I don't think it's `wp-signup.php`) so I can't look at the relevant code to debug it further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many hours of debugging and despair, the problem is now solved. It turned out to be a very obscure thing.

The redirect is issued by the function `ms_load_current_site_and_network()` inside `/wp-includes/ms-load.php`. It was issuing the redirect because `/wp-includes/ms-settings.php` was not able to set a domain. The reason it was not able to set a domain is because `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` was not set.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` not being set had to do with the PHP setting [auto_globals_jit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-globals-jit). It was set to On, resulting in the `$_SERVER` array not being set (as explained in [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php#69337)). Even though `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and the rest were defined when loading a single php file with `phpinfo();` in it, they were not defined when loading Wordpress's php files. And that led to the redirect.

Setting `auto_globals_jit` to Off in php.ini resolved it.

Bonus info:

The issue was additionally made more complicated by some form of caching (which I couldn't pin down or clear). So I had to rely on behavior that I saw occur only once and couldn't replicate afterwards. For example, I created a separate php file to just check if `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is set - and initially it wasn't. Following the suggestion from [the comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php#69337), I used `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` twice in the php file - and immediately saw that it was now set. However, when reverting the change and having `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` only once in the php file, it still remained set - suggesting I was seeing a cached response. I coulnd't get it to break again after I fixed it once.

Just documenting this here in case someone encounters similar behavior.

Comment: I want to thank you for doing the deep digging to find this bug. I have been wresting with the same issue for a while now and I was finally able to come across an answer that at least addressed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I can't comment so I'm leaving this answer. As a follow up to the fantastic research done by @Borislav there is another SE thread that is related, with several potential fixes:

[Site Redirecting to wp-signup.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165507/site-redirecting-to-wp-signup-php)

Ultimately, most redirect issues with WordPress Multisite seem related to `siteurl` and `home` which even if properly hardcoded (e.g. using `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` in the wp-config.php file) will still result in redirect issues if the accompanying fields in wp_options table are not also correct. This is due to the way that WordPress Multisite processes the initial setup routine; while I haven't found any documentation on the reason for this, I believe it was probably done on purpose by a Core dev to ensure no conflicts arise later on in the functionality of the Multisite installation, which is more prone to issues than single sites.

Some have suggested implementing `NOBLOGREDIRECT` as a fix but this does not work per se, and does not address the underlying issue. That setting is only meant to redirect visitors who land on non-existent sub-sites of your Multisite network (e.g. if registration is disabled for new blogs).

Ref: https://www.sarahgebauer.com/today-i-learned-multisite-mystery-signup/

Ref: https://gist.github.com/dejanmarkovic/8323792

In conclusion:

Always ensure that your wp_options table has the `siteurl` and `home` settings updated to accurately reflect the main domain of your Multisite installation. In certain cases, running a search/replace across the entire MySQL database may be required (depending on the history of your domain changes and database cruft), including any incorrect entries in the `wp_blogs` and `wp_site` tables if you moved your Multisite to a new domain recently...

Update: by the way, you will likely also experience this redirect issue if you are trying to convert a single site to Multisite network without using the Tools > Network Setup patch:

https://www.wpexplorer.com/quick-guide-wordpress-multisite-installation/

Comment: This was a huge help!! I definitely found until I had updated the `wp_blogs` and `wp_site` tables, that the redirect would not go away. I wish this answer was ranked higher and also was on the other Stack Exchange answer you linked above which I had also gone to first and found nothing worked.

Comment: you saved my sanity. thanks for the great explanations. Wordpress can be a voodoo sorcerer.

Answer (score 0):

Sifting through the entire MySQL is worth a shot for sure.  I fixed mine in `wp_domain_mapping` table the `id` was out a digit.. probably from adding, deleting and adding the alias back in and out.

FYI. Domain Mapping code kindly supplied by Humanmade http://www.easywebdesigntutorials.com/how-to-point-a-top-level-domain-to-a-multisite-using-domain-mapping/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).